# LINQ MVC ViewModel: Multiple joins to the same table with optional field

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Given the following database structure

## Category

ID
CategoryNameResID
ParentCategory(Optional)

## Resources

ID
Text
Lang

And given a ViewModel

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryNameResID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public string ParentCategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the list of all Categories with ParentCategoryName included

What I did so far is:

```
var categories = (from cat in db.Categories
                  join res in db.Resources on cat.CategoryNameResID equal res.ID
                  select new CategoryViewModel{
ID = cat.ID,
CategoryNameResID = cat.CategoryNameResID,
CategoryName = res.Text,
ParentCategory = cat.ParentCategory,
ParentCategoryName = (from p in db.Resources
where p.ID == cat.ParentCategory
select p.Text)
}).ToList();
```

I can't figure out how to get the ParentCategoryName without having to iterate again, which is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(from cat in cats
join res in resources on cat.ResId equals res.Id let categoryName = res.Text
join cat1 in cats on cat.ParentId equals cat1.Id into parentJoin
from pj in parentJoin.DefaultIfEmpty() let parentCatResId =pj==null?0: pj.ResId
join res1 in resources on parentCatResId equals res1.Id into resJoin
from res2 in resJoin.DefaultIfEmpty() let parentName = (res2==null?string.Empty:res2.Text)
    select new CategoryVM
    {
        Id = cat.Id,
        ResId = cat.ResId,
        CatName = categoryName,
        ParentId = cat.ParentId,
        ParentName = parentName
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: ParentID is not foreign key to Resources, what I need is the CategoryResId of the ParentID, because ParentID refers to and ID in categories

Comment: Yes, except this approach is only returning the rows that **HAVE** ParentCategory, what I need is actually all of them

Comment: This works but I'm a bit skeptical about the syntax!

Comment: LINQ only supports equi join.This is the only way I could find to acheve left join.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following data with your tables

```
dbo.Categories

ID  CategoryNameResID   ParentCategory
1   1                   NULL
2   2                   NULL
3   3                   1
4   4                   NULL
5   5                   4
6   6                   4
7   7                   4


dbo.Resources

ID  Text                Lang
1   Standard            en-GB
2   Custom              en-GB
3   Standard Oversize   en-GB
4   Loose               en-GB
5   Loose 2F Set        en-GB
6   Loose (4” Scale)    en-GB
7   Loose (6” Scale)    en-GB
```

The following LINQ statements will output the desired results:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryNameResID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public string ParentCategoryName { get; set; }
}   


var categories = (from cat in Categories
                  join res in Resources on cat.CategoryNameResID equals res.ID let categoryName = res.Text
                  select new CategoryViewModel
                  {
                    ID = cat.ID,
                    CategoryNameResID = cat.CategoryNameResID,
                    CategoryName = categoryName,
                    ParentCategory = cat.ParentCategory,    
                    ParentCategoryName = Resources.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID == cat.ParentCategory).Text
                  }).ToList();


foreach(var c in categories)
{
   Console.WriteLine(c.CategoryName + " - " + c.ParentCategoryName);   
}

// Prints
Standard - 
Custom - 
Standard Oversize - Standard
Loose - 
Loose 2F Set - Loose
Loose (4” Scale) - Loose
Loose (6” Scale) - Loose
```

Comment: `An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.`

Comment: Updated answer to use FirstOrDefault()

Comment: You're not getting the CategoryNameResID from the parent category, so you can't match it on Resources table...